# How can I iterate through a collection with underscore.js/lodash.js

Tags: collections, underscore.js, lodash

Minor problem. I have the collection

```
var allnames = {
    'names': 
     [
         { 'name': [ {'surname': 'moe'}, {'nickname': 'moose' } ] },
         { 'name': [ {'surname':'larry'}, {'nickname': 'lark' } ] }
     ]
};
```

and want to access/fetch each `'surname'` and `'nickname'`.

I have tried different options without any luck (e.g. `_.each`/`_.map`).

Is there anyone having experience in this area?

Comment: Can you add the desired javascript object/array you are hoping to extract from this? "Access/fetch" is a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

This snippet will turn the structure you have there into something that's easier to work with:

```
 var names = _.map( allnames.names, function(n){
    // n is an array with each object having one property; either a surname or a nickname
    return _.reduce(n.name, function(memo,part){ return _.extend(memo,part); }, {})
 });
```

Here names will be an array of objects with each object having a surname and a nickname:

```
[ { surname: 'moe', nickname: 'moose' }, { surname: 'larry', nickname: 'lark' } ]
```

Once you have that structure it's easy to manipulate that array to extract what you want e.g. get all the surnames:

```
var surnames = _.pluck(names, 'surname');
var nicknames = _.pluck(names, 'nickname');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I eventually found a solution, which covers what I was striving at

var allnames = {
    'names': 
     [
        { 'name': [ {'surname': 'moe'}, {'nickname': 'moose' } ] },
        { 'name': [ {'surname': 'larry'}, {'nickname': 'lark' } ] }
     ]
};

var surnames = [];
var nicknames = [];

function nameproc(myobj) 
{ 
    if ( myobj.surname ) 
    {
        surnames.push(myobj.surname);
        return myobj.surname
    }
    if( myobj.nickname) 
    {
        nicknames.push(myobj.nickname);
        return myobj.nickname;
    }
}

_.each(allnames.names, function(myobj) 
{ 
    _.each(myobj, function(nameobj) 
    {
        var nameobj = _.each(nameobj,nameproc);
    });
});

// Print out the surnames and nicknames

console.log(surnames);
console.log(nicknames);
```